# Black hole physics beyond the perturbation theory

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor

Motivated by this question: [Perturbation of a Schwarzschild Black Hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8307/)

How would one deal with the situation where black hole experiences not only small perturbations but major changes to the metric?

Answer (score 0):

Like in most physically complicated cases, one would normally solve the dynamic system [numerically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_relativity). In the case of general relativity, the "[3+1 decomposition](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0703035)" method or equivalent is used. There are some [open source tools](http://einsteintoolkit.org/) for aiding in numerical research.